# Перевод значения в мс от 00.01.1900 года в дату и время

Tags: javascript

Есть значение в мс  `43614696456`, отсчитанное от 01.01.1900 г. Как его можно преобразовать в значение вида `29.05.2019  16:42:15`? Может ли это сделать библиотека `moment`?

Comment: `new Date(43614696456)`

Comment: @nörbörnën "1971-05-20T19:11:36.456Z"

Comment: @nörbörnën, вроде написано, что `new Date` преобразует от 1970?

Comment: А точно в миллисекундах? У микрософта какой-то такой отсчет, я когда-то писал разбор даты, но уже не помню

Comment: @splash58, точно  в мс. Если число 43614696456 разделить на 1 000 000 и вставить в ексель и выбрать формат данных - дата. То в ячейке будет такой вид - `29.05.2019  16:42:15`

Comment: А почему вы делите на 1 000 000?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, `If the value needs to be processed using a different program, proceed as follows:

Divide Time_ms by 1,000,000.

Example: : 36343476928:1 000 000 = 36343,476928

The whole number portion (36344) is the date calculated from 31.12.1899.

Example: 36343 results in 02.07.1999

You can now convert the time stamp value to days in Excel by assigning a corresponding format from the "Date" group to the cells, which contain the time stamp.

Result: 37986 results in 31.12.2003

Comment: `36343` это число дней от 01.01.1900

Comment: `The value after the comma (0,476928) indicates the time:

Multiply the value (0.476928) by 24 to obtain the hours (11.446272).

Multiply the remainder (0.446272) by 60 results in the minutes (26.77632).

Multiply the remainder (0.77632) by 60 results in the seconds (46.5792).

Result 11:26:46.579

`

Comment: Чтобы из миллисекунд получить дни, нужно их разделить на число (1000 * 60 * 60) = 3 600 000. У вас не милисекунды

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект класса `Date` хранит число миллисекунд начиная от 1 января 1970 года. Т.к. у вас точка отсчета другая, то вам нужно прибавить к вашему значению дельту от 1 января 1900 до 1 января 1970.

И подумать, что делать с часовыми поясами

```js
const val = 43614696456;
const start = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
const date = new Date(val + start.valueOf());
console.log(date.toString());
```

Если же у вас не миллисекунды, а склеенное число дней и времени, то тогда нужно считать так

```js
const val = 43614696456;
const msecsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const ms = Math.round(val / 1E+6 * msecsPerDay);
const start = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
const date = new Date(ms + start.valueOf());
console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: @chupas я обновил ответ